# How to compare names with and without orthographic accent in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, spelling

In Python 3 and pandas I have a dataframe with full names. My default encoding is utf-8. The names are in the Portuguese language, therefore they have spelling accentuation

```
perfis_deputados.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 513 entries, 0 to 512
Data columns (total 10 columns):
data_nascimento    513 non-null object
e_mail             513 non-null object
link_api           513 non-null object
link_foto          513 non-null object
nome_completo      513 non-null object
nome_eleitoral     513 non-null object
partido            513 non-null object
sexo               513 non-null object
telefone           513 non-null object
uf                 513 non-null object
dtypes: object(10)
memory usage: 40.2+ KB
```

The columns "nome_completo" and "nome_eleitoral" have cases like:

```
AELTON JOSÉ DE FREITAS
JOÃO ALBERTO FRAGA SILVA
ALTINEU CÔRTES
```

I need to compare this dataframe with another - compare the names. But this second dataframe has names without any spelling accent. So the names appear like this, for example

```
AELTON JOSE DE FREITAS
JOAO ALBERTO FRAGA SILVA
ALTINEU CORTES
```

Please, is there a way to compare ignoring orthographic accenting? Or remove the spelling accent in the column I'm analyzing?

Comment: Have you tried looking at this page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define and apply function to your DF like this :

```
import unidecode
def f(str):
    return (unidecode.unidecode(str))

perfis_deputados["nome_completo"].apply(f)
```